# bash - meaning of "( doSomething ) || :"

Tags: bash, unix, solaris

I stumbled upon this line of code:

```
( cd ${TRASH_DIR} && rmdir 20* 2> /dev/null ) || :
```

The first expression is clear to me, but what is the meaning of the "else-Part": just "`:`"? Mostly I see "`|| exit 1`" in these cases, which is clear to me as well.

PS: Unfortunately I seem not to be able to google this character-combination without having a hint what it means...

Comment: You can with [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/)

Comment: `:` is a command that always and only returns true(0), this just means the command will exit true even if it fails.

Comment: @thomas ayoub: Thanks a lot for the symbolhound! Got it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition of meaning of the ":" shell character can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html). This is the snippet you need to locate; it is hard to be searched for on this lengthy page:

> `:` null command [colon]. This is the shell equivalent of a "NOP" (no op, a do-nothing operation). It may be considered a synonym for the shell builtin true. The ":" command is itself a Bash builtin, and its exit status is true (0).

In the code line you consider in your question, it is only used to ensure final exit code of 0 of the expression, independent from the conditions checked there.

Comment: Thank You: Found It now with symbolhound here on stackoverflow as well: In this case it was in the last line of the script for exiting successfull even if there were suppressed errors in the first expression

Comment: @evilive In that case you could just put `exit 0` at the end, which is obviously far clearer as this question wouldn't exist if the last person did that!

Comment: @123 Thank you! Just did that even before reading this ;)